# Need to find next node to insert in binary tree with less resources and performance usage

Tags: php, mysql, data-structures, query-optimization, binary-tree

Database tree Schema

| nodeid | nodeposition | nodeparentid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Left | NULL |
| 2 | Left | 1 |
| 3 | Right | 1 |
| 4 | Left | 2 |
| 5 | Right | 2 |
| 6 | Left | 3 |
| 7 | Right | 3 |
| 8 | Left | 4 |
| 9 | Right | 4 |

like this table increase continues when user submit tree form.

Have created a function to find next parent by given node value by BFS Method now facing performance issue,
having 200k rows when search for 1 it takes more resources and performance because it check every node, so made optimize code fetch the all rows from single query and perform logic from the value this will reduce database interaction but now all rows stored in memory when more users find next nodeparentid for each user all rows stored in memory so it cause issue need to optimize the code

current execution time is 80 seconds.

I have tried with below code snippet for find next parent node for given node

```
public function getNodeInsertPostionByParentId($parentIds)
{
    $parent = array('status' => false);
    $results = array();

    // Fetch all data from tree
    $qry = "SELECT nodeid, nodeposition, nodeparentid FROM tree ORDER BY nodeposition";
    $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($qry);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($nodeid, $nodeposition, $nodeparentid);

    // Create a map to store children for each parent
    $childrenMap = array();

    // Process query results
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $childrenMap[$nodeparentid][] = array('id' => $nodeid, 'position' => $nodeposition);
    }

    // Use BFS to process each parent ID
    $queue = $parentIds;

    while (!empty($queue)) {
        $currentParent = array_shift($queue);

        // Process the current parent
        $children = isset($childrenMap[$currentParent]) ? $childrenMap[$currentParent] : array();
        $count = count($children);

        if ($count == 2) {
            // Two children, recursively check each child
            foreach ($children as $child) {
                $queue[] = $child['id'];
            }
           
        } elseif ($count == 1) {
            // One child, set position to 'Right' or 'Left' based on the child's ID
            $parent['status'] = true;
            $parent['parentId'] = $currentParent;
            $parent['node'] = 'Right';
            break;
        } elseif ($count == 0) {
            // No children, set position to 'Right' or 'Left' based on the current parent's ID
            $parent['status'] = true;
            $parent['parentId'] = $currentParent;
            $parent['node'] = 'Left';
            break;
        }
    }

    // Return the processed results
    return $parent;
}

$yourInstance = new YourClassName();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($yourInstance->getNodeInsertPostionByParentId(array('1')));
```

in which way we can reduce the execution time with less resources.

Tree view from above data

```
             1 
         /        \
        2          3 
      /    \      / \
     4      5    6  7 
    / \    / \
   8   9  10
```

- if search for 1 to get the next node to insert 5 right as output
- if search for 6 to get the next node to insert 6 left as output
- if search for 3 to get the next node to insert 6 left as output
- if search for 2 to get the next node to insert 5 right as output

any suggestion or code will helpful

Comment: Suggest looking at recursive CTEs. These enable database kind of search functions without having to do it in PHP. If you are doing SQL queries in a PHP loop there's a fair chance its unoptimized SQL or data structures.

Comment: Checked recursive CTE using with recursive like that can you pls explain how to do that because beginner in this area mysql 7.0 is using

Comment: So MySQL 7.0 as in MySQL cluster? Its an odd version number. Can you provide some expected results of a query for data items using your sample set. Edit the question with details.

Comment: sample data showed and using phpmyadmin mysql, not in cluster

Comment: There is no MySQL 7. There is MySQL 5.7 (which doesnt support CTEs) and MySQL 8 (which does). So telling us your MySQL version is required for an answer. Your phpmyadmin version is not relevant. Also, for a complete binary tree, you do not have to walk through the tree to know the number of the parent or the children. It can be directly calculated from the index (which is the beauty of a complete binary tree). Not sure though if you just simplified your tasks.

Comment: oops. right MySQL 5.7 is my version can you pls some code or how to do that for my function code logic.

Comment: Unfortunately, MySQL 5.7 is limited for such queries. For your tree, if you want to find the first missing node from the top, you have to potentially check all nodes, so it gets slower with size. You should try to either specify some boundary conditions (e.g. "always look from a very deep node"), find a different implementation or workaround (you might e.g. keep a list of free nodes, use paths instead of a linked list, ...). See e.g. [How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20215744) for problems with this query type and/or other tricks/implementations.

Comment: Please elaborate on what the goal of the code is.  Hammers don't work well with screws; screwdrivers don't work well with nails.

Answer (score 0):

If you are fetching one parent for one node, then that can be achieved by having the parentid in the table with each row.  That will take a few milliseconds per fetch.

If you fetching the ancestors of a given node, even repeated application of the above fetch would take much less than 1 second.  And even faster if CTEs were available.  Note:  This does not need a binary tree.

If you are modifying the tree (adding/deleting/rearranging nodes), then storing all the data and fetching the entire set is terribly inefficient.

If you are 'playing' with binary trees, why are you reloading it repeatedly?

If you discover a "left-right" or "red-black" tree, do not use a database for that; it is terribly inefficient when modifying the data.

A priority queue is very efficient but only if it is entirely in RAM; it is inefficient to store on disk.